# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]:

Tags: sql, database

```
<?php
include('connect.php'); 
$date = $_POST['date'];
$student_ID = $_POST['student_ID'];
$full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
$year_section = $_POST['year_section'];
$payment_description = $_POST['payment_description'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$received_by = $_POST['received_by'];

// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO transaction (date,student_ID,full_name,year_section,payment_description,amount,received_by) VALUES (:sas,:asas,:asafs,:offff,:statttt,:dot,:rd,:ft)";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q>execute(array(':sas'=>$date,':asas'=>$student_ID,':asafs'=>$full_name,':offff'=>$year_section,':statttt'=>$payment_description,':dot'=>$amount,':rd'=>$received_by));
header("location: index.php");
?>
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\recordmanagement\main\reg.php:15 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\recordmanagement\main\reg.php(15):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\recordmanagement\main\reg.php on line 15

In the code I am also unsure about the meaning of these values:

```
 (:sas,:asas,:asafs,:offff,:statttt,:dot,:rd,:ft);
```

I downloaded it from sourcecode, so it was not written by me.

Comment: @Alex K. Why was this question turned into a community wiki?

Comment: This question was turned into a community wiki because both reviewers and people who suggest edits are not doing what they are supposed to do. It took 12 revisions before the post became good enough, this should have been done with just 1. A post becomes community wiki after 10 revisions.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I see. I didn't know that posts turned into wikis after a certain number of revisions. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a field to much in the query. This:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO transaction 
(date,student_ID,full_name,year_section,payment_description,amount,received_by) 
VALUES (:sas,:asas,:asafs,:offff,:statttt,:dot,:rd,:ft)";
```

should probably be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO transaction 
(date,student_ID,full_name,year_section,payment_description,amount,received_by) 
VALUES (:sas,:asas,:asafs,:offff,:statttt,:dot,:rd)";
```

as there is no matching value for the `:ft` field.

Whether this is because your missing an item in the values or if it's not needed I can't say.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) Could you tell me if what is the meaning of this codes? (:sas,:asas,:asafs,:offff,:statttt,:dot,:rd)";

Comment: @user3350719 I think they're just placeholders to indicate what items should be replaced with data in the execute that follows.

Comment: These are late variable bindings. First you must indicate what variables are used in query (VALUES(...)), after that you bind actual values of variables (execute(array(...))). Of course both the number and types of variables must match values in the table to which you are inserting data.